# Disc of convergence of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find the disc of convergence: $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-n^3}z^n$$

I have been manipulating the power series and I am pretty sure it has something to do with $e$ but I cannot seemed to get it manipulated in the right form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-n^3}z^n$ be a given power series. Using the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Application_to_power_series), the radius of convergence $R$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
R&=\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-n^3}\right)^{1/n}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-n^2}}\\\\
&=1/e
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

As $n\to\infty$ we have $\lim (1-1/n^2)^{-n^2} = e$ in light of $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+a/x)^x =e^a$.  Because of this the coefficients of the series are like $e^n$.  The radius of convergence is therefore $e^{-1}$.

In more detail:  For each $\epsilon$ you can find $N$ such that $e-\epsilon\le (1-1/n^2)^{-n^2}\le e+\epsilon$ for $n\ge N$.  The absolute values of the terms are therefore between $|(e-\epsilon)z|^n$ and $|(e+\epsilon)z|^n$ for $n\ge N$, and so the series converges for $|z|<1/(e+\epsilon)$ and diverges for $|z|>1/(e-\epsilon)$.